# How can I get Sails.js logging to use multiple Winston transports with different log levels?

Tags: logging, sails.js, winston

After searching the Sails.js docs, GitHub issues, Google group, and here on SO, I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

I want to use Winston to log with 3 different transports, at 3 different log levels:

- `warn` logs to the [Sentry](https://github.com/guzru/winston-sentry) transport
- `info` logs to the [Loggly](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#loggly-transport) transport
- `verbose` logs to the [Console](https://github.com/flatiron/winston#console-transport) transport

In my `config/log.js` file I have the following:

```js
var Winston = require('winston');
var Loggly = require('winston-loggly');
var Sentry = require('winston-sentry');

module.exports.log = {

  // Without this the log level is prefixed to messages twice 
  // for some reason...
  prefixes: {}, 

  // Without this, Winston Sails seems to only send "info" 
  // logs to Winston (Sails' default log level)...
  level: 'verbose', 

  custom: new Winston.Logger({
    transports: [

      new Winston.transports.Sentry({
        level: 'warn',
        dsn: '{my account dsn}',
        patchGlobal: true
      }),

      new Winston.transports.Loggly({
        level: 'info',
        subdomain: '{my subdomain}',
        inoputToken: '{my input token}'
      }),

      new Winston.transports.Console({
        level: 'verbose'
      })

    ]
  })
};
```

But with the above setup there are a bunch of problems:

- `verbose` logs are getting sent to Loggly...
- Only `root` errors are showing up in Sentry, which I think comes from the `patchGlobal` option. No warnings and none of the "Possibly Uncaught Exception" errors from rejected Bluebird promises.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a heads up: There is a double typo on `var Loggly = require('winston-longly'):`. I guess it should be `winston-loggly` and end the line with a `;`, right?

Comment: Good catch @Murilo, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Well, looks like Winston writes to logs based on their numeric levels. So that error messages will be always written to info log, but info never to error log.

So I think it is better to separate to different instances in **config/bootstrap.js**:

```js
sails.warnLog = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Sentry)({
          name: 'warn-Sentry',
          dsn: '{my account dsn}',
          patchGlobal: true
          level: 'warn'
        })
      ]});

sails.infLog = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Loggly)({
          name: 'info-Loggly',
          subdomain: '{my subdomain}',
          inputToken: '{my input token}'
          level: 'info'
        })
      ]});

sails.verbLog = new (winston.Logger)({
      transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
          name: 'verb-console',
          timestamp: true,
          prettyPrint: true,
          colorize: true,
          level: 'verbose'
        })
      ]});
```

And then you can write to log:

```js
sails.warnLog.warn('Warning');
sails.infLog.info('Information');
sails.verbLog.verbose('Verbose');
```

In fact, I do not like this way. It is ugly =(